# como asignarle un valor a un select a partir de los datos guardados en firebase (cloud)

Tags: java, html, firebase

estoy tratando de recuperar datos de una base de datos firebase en mi sitio web

```
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input id="id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID del usuario" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
    <button id="buscar" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" onclick="buscar()">Buscar ID</button>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Nombre</span>
    <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Apellido</span>
    <input id="apellido" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>


  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Seleccion 1</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="estudio">
      <option selected>Opciones</option>
      <option value="1">opcion1</option>
      <option value="2">opcion2</option>
      <option value="3">opcion3</option>
   
    </select>
  </div>
```

luego este es mi js

```
 function buscar(){

  var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
  var docRef3 = db.collection("basededatos").doc(id);

docRef3.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value = doc.data().nombre;
      var apellido= document.getElementById('apellido').value = doc.data().apellido;
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
}
```

Hasta aqui todo muy bien ... agrego el id ... presiono buscar y trae el nombre y el apellido desde la base de datos ... pero a pesar de muchos intentos e ideas para poder traer la info del select no logro encontrar la mecanica correcta para poder hacerlo desde la base de datos y actualizar el select ... agradecere cualquier ayuda ...Saludos!

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a esta parte de tu código: `if (doc.exists) {` allí ya obtienes con éxito el nombre y el apellido, según dices ... ¿estoy en lo cierto? Pues bien, allí no se ve ningún intento de llenar ningún select. Conviene que indiques qué estás intentando y eventualmente cómo están estructurados los datos en Firebase.

Comment: Tenia la esperanza de que pudiera ser tan simple como xD aahah pero claramente no 
`var estudio= document.getElementById('estudio').value = doc.data().estudio;`

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu comentario. Si quieres llenar los `option` de un `select` con los datos supongo que tendrás que leer el nodo donde están esos option y mostrarlos en el `select`, mediante un bucle o de otro modo, todo depende de cómo estén los datos en Firebase. Es información esencial que no aparece en tu pregunta.